# requests.get method takes huge time for zip file in python

Tags: python, python-requests

I have a website with huge number of pdfs, zip files, images, ppt, html links. So I use python requests method to check if files ( pdfs, zip, images, links etc) is not broken. But when the link passed is a zip file whose size is huge "get" method takes time to send the response. So wanted to know if there is alternative to check if the passed link( can be image, zip file, html page) is not broken.

```
response = requests.get(pageURL)
if (response.status_code ==404):
    #print("Broken Link")
```

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/66710209/202168

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`requests.get` is downloading the files, th't why it's taking so long. Use `requests.head` to get only the response

```
response = requests.head(url)
```

Another thing you can do is to open a `Session` one time instead of opening a socket in every call

```
urls = [...]
with requests.Session() as session:
    for url in urls:
        response = session.head(url)
```